# Can't play FLV in WordPress website

Tags: video-player

May be I am asking a stupid question, but I am really stuck that I am unable to play .flv videos directly on my webpage.

Since I have VLC media player installed in my computer, it asks for permission to play the video through my VLC media player web plugin.

[image: FLV Playing Issue]

I tried to play the .flv video with JW Player, and it is working properly. But the problem is JW Wordpress uses a shortcode, that is being inserted automatically in description of email newsletter. That is why I am unable to use JW Player also.

**I have ffmpeg, flvtool2, flvtool++ installed. Do I need anything else to install via SSH to get .flv play on web?**

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The things you have installed on your webserver have nothing to do with whether or not the client can play the video served by your server, that depends on what you implement on the client side.

Besides that the FLV container format is becoming deprecated with the increased support of HTML5 and I wouldn't recommend using FLV in any new web project that doesn't need high compatibility to absolutely every older browser.
MP4 is [supported in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/mpeg4) except for Opera, it doesn't need any plugins or special players on your website, you can just use the HTML5 `<video>` tag.

Its extremely easy to implement and is very well supported.

If you have questions about how to setup things in wordpress you should better ask that on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.